# Rails form_for does not do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a problem with Ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0.

I have a form_for creating a new "Project" entry which has title, description and status.
Form itself used to work like a charm, till I did something and I have no idea what. Problem is, form renders perfectly, but after adding VALID values to it and pressing submit button it does nothing. If I refresh form before entering values and submitting, url changes to something like:

> projects/new?utf8=✓&authenticity_token=Xh6ZGV2vvth1RzhBk3g5zonms%2Fdq3yzaJtzxDU%2FFBiM%3D&project%5Btitle%5D=Project+title&project%5Bdescription%5D=description&project%5Bstatus%5D=Ongoing&commit=Submit

And the weird thing is, if I add another, exactly the same form after first one in the same file, the second form works perfectly.

My projects new.html.erb

```
<h1>Create a new project</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <%= form_for @project do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
      <%= f.label :status %>
      <%= f.select :status, [['Ongoing', 'Ongoing'],['Suspended','Suspended'],['Finished','Finished']] %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

projects_controller.erb

```
  def new
      @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Project successfully created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :status)
  end
```

And as I said, it used to work with no problem before.
Also I have tried to disable JS, but it still did not worked. 
If you have any ideas where the problem might be, please let me know. Thank you.

EDIT:

HTML generated from the new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">

      <h1>Create a new project</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/projects" class="new_project" id="new_project" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Xh6ZGV2vvth1RzhBk3g5zonms/dq3yzaJtzxDU/FBiM=" /></div>
      <label for="project_title">Title</label>
      <input id="project_title" name="project[title]" type="text" />
      <label for="project_description">Description</label>
      <input id="project_description" name="project[description]" type="text" />
      <label for="project_status">Status</label>
      <select id="project_status" name="project[status]"><option value="Ongoing">Ongoing</option>
<option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
<option value="Finished">Finished</option></select>
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>  </div>
</div>

    </div>
```

Added log after submitting form:

```
Started GET "/projects/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=Xh6ZGV2vvth1RzhBk3g5zonms%2Fdq3yzaJtzxDU%2FFBiM%3D&project%5Btitle%5D=Project+title&project%5Bdescription%5D=description+of+the+project&project%5Bstatus%5D=Ongoing&commit=Submit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xh6ZGV2vvth1RzhBk3g5zonms/dq3yzaJtzxDU/FBiM=", "project"=>{"title"=>"Project title", "description"=>"description of the project", "status"=>"Ongoing"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendered projects/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 10.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/rails_bootstrap_forms.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/project.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/projects.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/project.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/projects.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 20:44:39 +0100
```

Comment: Can you please paste HTML generated by first code snippet?

Comment: Your request is sending data in get request can you paste your form tag's generated html over here?

Comment: Added HTML generated by new.html.erb

Comment: Post your `log` after submitting the form.

Comment: Added log after submitting form.

Comment: Very Weird! Everything seems fine for me.

Comment: Can you share your `projects` routes from `routes.rb`.

Comment: Another weird thing. Just generated another model with rails scaffold and get exactly the same problem!

Comment: Kirti Throrat, it is almost empty - 
 root 'projects#index'
  resources :projects

Comment: Thanks Epus. One more thing, can you share the `Project` model code in the question.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your application_controller.rb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not coming from rails, perhaps an extension of your browser such as a developer tool, or perhaps a configuration of your web server

1. Try using another browser to access your form, preferably one that has no or little extensions
2. If it's not working use firebug and see in Net tab if you are redirected from a POST to a GET request after submitting
3. Use another webserver, switch to webrick, thin, puma or anything else and check

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the source of the problem?

Comment: Long story short: used your advise to look for problem outside rails, so tried different browsers, web servers still got same error, so changed db to sqlite and to mysql latter and on both of them everything worked fine, than moved back to postgresql and problem is gone. Weird things happens.

Comment: Weird things happens indeed :)